# Tests Struts2 struts.xml with simple junit

Tags: struts2, junit, struts, struts2-config-browser

I just want a basic Junit that that will test loading the configuration file struts.xml and making sure all the classes can be found and such.

I'm using the struts junit 2.2.1 plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [**`Config Browser Plugin`**](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html) of Struts2.

Description :

> The Config Browser Plugin is a simple tool to help view an application's configuration at runtime. It is very useful when debugging problems that could be related to configuration issues.

Comment: looks cool, but I want something I can turn into a junit.  I will use this to fail my hudson builds, so the people who break it get emails.  Its not for me.